# Where to add identifier for NSTableView column?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, nstableview

I can't find where I can enter the identifier for an NSTableView column in XCode 6 beta 6. In XCode 5 I would select the following object in my object hierarchy:

Bordered Scroll View > Clip View > Table View > **Table Column**

Then I would show the Identity Inspector which would show an Identity section with a text field named "identifier" into which I would type the cell identifier.

I can find no such field in XC6b6. There's a "Restoration ID" field which I tried out of desperation, but that caused a whole lot of nasty error messages, so that's obviously not it.

Where do you put the cell identifier nowadays? Thanks.

PS, my columns currently have identifiers like this, so I guess I can at least continue and come back to this later, but it would be nice to be able to set the identifier to something else:

AutomaticTableColumnIdentifier.0

AutomaticTableColumnIdentifier.1

AutomaticTableColumnIdentifier.etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the "Restoration ID" field. At least, when I open a NIB created in Xcode 5.x that had identifiers assigned to columns and cell views, that's where they show up in Xcode 6 GM seed.

What "nasty error messages" did you get? I recommend attempting to understand what they were trying to tell you.

Comment: Well, now this is awkward. I went to try it again, given your response, and now it works! I can't imagine I entered it for the wrong level in the tree, because I double-checked it in order to document it above. I don't know, but it works. Thanks for your response. XCode and me aren't very good friends yet (I'm too used to Visual Studio for web services in my day job).

Answer (score 0):

In the Identity Inspector -> "User defined runtime attributes" add the attribute and change keyPath to "identifier", change type to "String", then change value to your desire identifier